# how to use SpriteBatch draw method

Tags: java, libgdx

```
SpriteBatch batcher = new SpriteBatch();
batcher.draw(TextureRegion region,
             float x,
             float y,
             float originX,
             float originY,
             float width,
             float height,
             float scaleX,
             float scaleY,
             float rotation)
```

What is the meaning of `originX`, `originY`, `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `rotation`? Also can you please give me an example of their use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you look into [docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20boolean%29) ?

As stated in docs, origin is bottom left corner, `originX`, `originY` are offsets from this origin.
For example if you want object rotate around his center, you will do this.

```
originX = width/2;
originY = height/2;
```

By specifing `scaleX`, `scaleY`, you scale the image, if you want to make Sprite 2x larger, you will set both scaleX and scaleY to number `2`.

`rotation` specifies rotation around origin in degrees.

**This code snippet draws texture rotated by 90 degrees around its center**

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

int textureWidth = texture.getWidth();
int textureHeight = texture.getHeight();
float rotationAngle = 90f;

TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight);

batch.begin();
batch.draw(region, 0, 0, textureWidth / 2f, textureHeight / 2f, textureWidth, textureHeight, 1, 1, rotationAngle, false);
batch.end();
```

or take a look at tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have already seen docs but I can not understand how to rotate texture with draw method. If u have any example then please show to me.

Comment: Texture ball = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/lion.png")); TextureRegion ballRegion = new TextureRegion(ball,0,0,64,64); batcher.draw(ballRegion, 160 - 32/2, 240 - 32/2,10,10,64,64,20,20,45); I want to rotate texture ball at 90 degree angle ..